# Ruby add nil value to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I initialize an array and be able to add nil value to it? as I know Array.wrap doesn't do the job.

```
list = Array.wrap(nil) => []
```

What I want:

```
list = Array.add(nil) => [nil]
```

Thank you

Comment: How about using literal syntax `[nil]`

Comment: Based on the comments it appears that the question is, “How can I create an array that contains a single, given object?”. Correct? If so, do as @engineersmnky suggests, replacing `nil` with the given object if it is something other than `nil`. If the object is held by a variable `x`, write `[x]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for ([Rails](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.0.0.1/Array/wrap/class)):

```
list = Array.wrap([nil])
#=> [nil]
```

But why not just a simple `list = [nil]`, as per @engineersmnky's comment?

Also `list = Array.new.push nil`, but it's still better the easy way above.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
list = Array.new(1)
```

The number fed in as an argument dictates how many nils are added:

```
list = Array.new(3)
=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: I'm adding a variable to the array and I don't know if its nil or not. like Array.wrap(item)

Comment: @nanakondor just write `[item]`

Comment: The question was literally `How can I initialize an array and be able to add nil value to it?`

Comment: @nanakondor What @Stefan said but if `item` can also be an `Array` I would change this to `[*item]` to better simulate the way `Array#wrap` works (which by the way is a rails method so I added the rails tag.

Comment: @engineersmnky although having to deal with objects that can either be `nil` or arrays or non-arrays might indicate some underlying problems.

Comment: @Stefan no argument here